# How do you print an error from a child thread in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Given the following code:

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent

main :: IO ()
main = forkIO errorPrinter >> threadDelay 1000000 >> print "Finished"

errorPrinter = error "You can't see me!"
```

I would expect, that upon running this code I would see this:

```
"You can't see me"
"Finished!"
```

Printed to the console. However, "You can't see me" is never printed.

I realise that using error is not a good idea in production code, but I use it in development and I find that no errors are printed to the console - even those raised by dependencies.

I am sure this problem has an easy solution. I can't be the first person to have this issue, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As soon as the main thread is over, all others are killed. You should make the main thread wait for the other. Check the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#g:12) about "Terminating the program" for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Did you notice the call to threadDelay? I think that should pause the main thread long enough to allow the child thread to complete.

Comment: That's right, I don't know why the delay does not help.

Comment: Actually, it does - this seems to have something to do with stack rather than Haskell itself (see my comment below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem; for me, it does print "You can't see me!":

```
% runhaskell test.hs
test.hs: You can't see me!
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at test.hs:8:16 in main:Main
"Finished"
```

I see similar behavior as far back as GHC 7.6 (the oldest GHC I have lying around); I would be mildly surprised to learn that this behavior has changed significantly in the last twenty years or so.

Anyway I would recommend switching over to printing the message you want printed:

```
import System.IO
errorPrinter = hPutStrLn stderr "You can't see me!"
```

Say what you mean, and all that.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The problem is that other errors, from dependencies don't print either. I will use your idiom for printing errors since it does look better. 

This is rather odd, since it occurs in several different projects. I didn't really think it was worth mentioning that I am using stack to manage the project, but maybe I should investigate that avenue...

Comment: ...and it turns out that I should have! It works if compiled with ghc but not with stack. OK, thanks again for your help - I'll go and look into this a little further.